# Extract Links and save pages

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

I have a couple of pages, each has around 20 links on it. Each link leads to a different page.

I want to provide the user an option to extract all the links on these Page and then download each of the pages(20) to their desktop.

Any tools/addons/plugins that I can suggest users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Webreaper](http://www.webreaper.net/) will let you do this, though it's not an addon but rather a full-blown app.  It will adjust the links for local browsing as well.

Comment: looks like a nice one..do you also know of any addons..firefox usually has these funky but useful addons :) thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

[Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427) is one of the best Firefox extensions IMHO to this task.

If you want a solution outside Firefox, try [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).